# C T Ds. Whats the 4th symbol

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

So today i decided to attempt puzzle constructing-for the very first time.

The three puzzles below contain a hidden symbol, each symbol is somewhat related to one another. Use the arrows to find out the identity of each puzzle. Then come to a conclusion of what the 4th symbol would be if it had a puzzle.

Hint

> the **specific** colors of the dots do not matter. But color matters

Hint 2, even more hintier

> just because you can't see it, doesn't mean that it's not there.

Hint 3

> Don't pick up your pencil

[image]

Comment: @TylerJohnson making out that a popular good moderator threatened to ban you and the excessive bad language is not going to go down well in the is community. Plus the puzzle is not the best...

Comment: Puzzle is not the best? Can you solve it?

Comment: @TylerJohnson I'm not even sure how you are supposed to solve it... Can you elaborate in the question?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil sure, i explained the question a bit more throughly in my current edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting at, what is, in my mind, the greenest dot and following the instructions, I make

> A, C, F

My guess at the pattern is

> skip one, then two, then three

In which case the next symbol to make is

> J

And we can make this symbol by

> Three dots in a backwards L, greenest at the top. Then Two vertical descending arrows, followed by a Counterclockwise Left arrow

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Good job!

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer

The first symbol is

> ...something like a capital "A".

The 2nd symbol is

> ...something like a "crescent moon."

The 3rd symbol is

> ...a "+"

But I'm not sure what those three add up to.

Methodology:

> Put your pen on the paper and follow the instructions given by the arrows.  You'll end up with a symbol which connects the dots.

Comment: You almost had it!